# What is meant by "unit" in IDEA code duplication analysis?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA has an ability to find duplicated code.
One can tune the amount of "units" (according to [their documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-duplication-analysis-settings.html)) that is considered duplicate.
However, I can't find any explanation on what is this "unit".

I'm looking for an answer that unambiguously defines such units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "units" measure is used in option `Do not show duplicates simpler than`. This option defines the minimal weight of the reported code fragments. 
This weight is computed as a sum of all element weights in the fragment.
And since different elements have the different weights sum of them must be measured in abstract "units".

Element weight can be roughly approximated as:

- it's a statement -> 2
- it's an expression/literal/identifier -> 1
- otherwise -> 0

For example, weight of `x = 42;` can be approximated as `w(x) + w(=) + w(42) + w(;) + w(statement(x=42;))`. Which is rougly `1 + 0 + 1 + 2 = 4` .

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @PawelVeselov no, you can only learn it from the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/duplicates-analysis/src/com/intellij/dupLocator).

Comment: the PyCharm documentation contains the formula `units = 2*<number of statements> + <number of expressions>` at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/analyzing-duplicates.html#configure-duplicates-analysis